# ASP.NET code to receive IM using lync SDK 2013 (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, lync, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I am a beginner in this field and learning how to send and receive IM using lync SDK 2013.
i have gone through and understood how to send IM using lync SDK 2013.
Now I want to learn how to receive IM using the same. 
can anyone help me with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty resources in the internet which can be helpful:

- [Learn Skype Web SDK Day 15 : Receiving Instant Messages](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/05/learn-skype-web-sdk-day-15-receiving-instant-messages/)
- [Send and receive text in a conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/sendreceivetext)
- [Receive an Incoming IM Call](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-Communication-IncomingIMCall)
- [Skype Web SDK Sending an Instant Message](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1028485/Skype-Web-SDK-Sending-an-Instant-Message)

However it totally depends on your needs and what you wish to build, so its not that easy to answer (e.g. Error Handling if the user is offline or not, and such stuff).

Comment: wont defining some handlers help ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Lync 2013 client SDK has a hard dependency on the Lync 2013 client application. That is, you app can only run on a computer where the Lync 2013 client is installed and can run. This is because the SDK depends on the SIP protocol stack that lives in the client.
If you want to send and receive IM in an ASP.NET app, you'll need to use our Skype Web SDK, as was indicated in the first answer.